# Using an HTML template across multiple subdirectories

Tags: html, css, xml, templates

I run a website for my photography where I have a stories page (http://www.traumantic.com/stories.htm) that is a long list of choices that lead to a sub folder and a gallery of images for that session.

I have an index.htm file in each of those folders that displays the gallery chosen.

I am trying to develop a new format for my pages, and putting it in place means replacing dozens of index.htm files and editing each one for that new format.  A boatload of work.

I have noted that a lot of news sites seems to have a method of using a single template for the main body of the page and the elements of the news story are pulled in from another source.

I figured I could do this with XML like I did with my galleries, but I am lost.

I tried creating an XML file in a couple of text folders and then reading that form an HTM file two levels up.  Didn't work.

Currently when you click on a link on my stories page, it opens the index.htm file in a sub-folder.

What I want to happen is this.

Clicking on a choice on my stories page launches an html template that reads the details from the folder.

The one html template would be used for all of the different story folders below.  Making it far easier to modify the look of my web site quickly.

I'd rather put a ton a of work into designing this system that doing a mass replace and edit project on hundreds of files.

I hope this makes sense to some of you and that you can guide me to some study topics that will help me learn how to do this.

I am seeking advice on places where I can see example of this process.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to use an iframe 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

```
<iframe src="/path/to/file.html"></iframe>
```

Searching "html include" will yield a few guides that have various JavaScript implementations. (e.g., https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

If you're able to run php, you could use `include` 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

But at that point, you might want to consider installing some sort of template engine like twig https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/intro.html